# 2D map from .xyz file

Tags: python

I'm a Python beginner and would like to create a 2D map from data in a .xyz file as shown below :

```
...
13 0 -0.11298451 
14 0 -0.10656391 
15 0 Nodata 
16 0 Nodata 
17 0 Nodata 
....
```

The first column is `x`, the second `y`, and the third `z`. 
Each time there is data in the third column I would like to set a black pixel, and each time there is `Nodata` a white pixel. At the end, I would like to get a map as shown in the figure below with x and y axis.

Could someone advise how to start?
I have started to write a small code but I have no idea how to continue 
Many thanks for your help!

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
x = pd.read_csv('path/data.txt',sep=' ',usecols=[0], header=None)
y = pd.read_csv('path/data.txt',sep=' ',usecols=[1], header=None)
z = pd.read_csv('path/data.txt',sep=' ',usecols=[2], header=None)
X,Y=np.meshgrid(x,y)
```

[image]

Comment: You could use a library called cv2 and loop through every line in the file. If there exists some data in the z you can change the pixel of the image to black.

Comment: or you can use `pillow`

Comment: Are x and y ordered integers as indicated by your example (x: 0-1-2-0-1-2, y: 0-0-0-1-1-1)? Maybe you can provide a link to a sample input?

Comment: Many thanks for your recommandation! Here a link for downloading data: https://filesender.renater.fr/?s=download&token=1f4d8542-c19c-4905-bed8-7f04608318bd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can load this file into a numpy array using [`np.genfromtxt`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) and create a 0-1 mask from it:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#load data into numpy array
my_data = np.genfromtxt("Essais1.prn")
#extract z-data and reshape into form x * y
z=my_data[:, 2].reshape(np.unique(my_data[:, 1]).size, np.unique(my_data[:, 0]).size)

#set NaN values to 0, everything else to 1
mask = np.where(np.isnan(z), 0, 1)

#display the mask with grayscale colormap
plt.imshow(mask, cmap="Greys", origin="lower")
#plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

Sample output:
[image]

Comment: I would like to create now a cartography from the same data but using the z value (third column) with the real value and thus having a color scale like that : https://filesender.renater.fr/?s=download&token=f0e2d41b-7ee0-4ce5-8bee-074e4462d9ec
Can I use the same methodology?

Comment: Then you should ask another question. Questions and answers should be problem-focused and not mix various problems or alter the question according to follow-up problems. In general, the approach is transferable but you have to set[ only NaN values to zero](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nan_to_num.html) while not changing the other values and you might want to adapt the colormap `cmap`.